# Azure CLI cannot find blob in storage container when using CLI

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I'm relatively new to azure especially through using Azure CLI and need to find a way to download blob storage for a customer using a SAS token that I can use in a script.

So far I'm using this command, however it always tells me the blob does not exist however as far as I can tell the blob both exists and the syntax in the command is correct:

```
az storage blob download -c $containername--account-name $storageaccountname -f aztest --name $filepathwithname -f tempfile --sas-token $SAStoken
```

here the $filepath looks like "sql$2021/folder1/folder2/targetfile" where sql$2021 is the first folder I see inside the storage account container

As far as I can tell this is the correct syntax, and have tried adjusting qoutes etc and copying location of the file from azure storage manager however it still returns an error message saying the blob doesn't exist:

```
At C:\Users\me\blob_download.ps1:3 char:1
+ az storage blob download -c $container--account-name $accountname -f ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Client-R...ssage></Error>.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
ERROR: The specified blob does not exist. ErrorCode: BlobNotFound
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>BlobNotFound</Code><Message>The specified blob does not exist.
```

What is it that I'm missing or otherwise using incorrectly, this should be a very simple command to write, however its given me a lot of grief.

Comment: I would suggest that try this command to see what its happening: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_list. Try to list the blobs inside the folder and see if you find the blob and if there is something different than what you are looking for.

Comment: I've used azure blob list prior to writing this command, but I've done so again and the file is returned when using list command. I've therefore copied the name field straight from that into the script to use, but still doesn't find a match. Could this be a formatting issue due to the use of the $ character in the powershell script?

Comment: mmm, yeah I think that can be, it's a bad practice to add special characters to a folder name, although the folders in the storage are virtual folders. I will try to create a test blob with a folder name without any special characters and I will try again the script with that blob, and see what happend, cause I don't see anythink wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to echo the advice not to use special characters in your folder/file names.  Even so, at some point we all run into special characters and a useful approach is to double wrap the string with single and double quotes like this:

```
'"file$name.txt"'
```

These are some resources that go into more detail:

- [Use Azure CLI effectively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively)
- [Quoting issues with PowerShell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/quoting-issues-with-powershell.md)
- [Escaping the pipe character in PowerShell commands](https://octopus.com/blog/powershell-pipe-escaping)

(*Note*:  You are missing a space between $containername and --account-name, and use -f twice in the example you gave.  I would give that a quick revisit.)

I tried both double quotes and wrapping single quotes around double quotes.  Double quotes did not work (you can see the $ not being taken as text in the first example) while wrapping single quotes around double quotes did:

[image]

[image]

You'll notice the error I got was, "Authentication failure.  This may be caused by either invalid account key, connection string or sas token value provided for your storage account."

I was getting a very similar error to yours with my test file that did not have a special character prior to double wrapping my sas key ("The specified resource does not exist.  ErrorCode: ResourceNotFound"):

[image]

[image]

In either case, I hopes this helps!

```
$SASToken = '"sp=racw&st=2021-08-26T01:13:44Z&se=2021-08-26T09:13:44Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=b&sig=Eu5SohLylE%2F12dxsNlKAw9qPMA7TKx9PguaCDpW60GI%3D"'

az storage blob download --container-name "kobulloc-container-specialcharblob" --file "C:\testimage.png" --name '"busines$penguin.png"' --account-name "kobulloc210825spccharblb" --sas-token $SASToken
```